# Is heating and cooling a microcontroller frequently a good thing?

Tags: microcontroller, led, temperature, microprocessor

Consider the chip rated to operate at -45..125°C , the chip has internal temperature sensor. Basically the chip will drive an LED.

Chip has on different plane and LED is in different PCB plane. Plane is stitched together to allow path to measure the temperature of LED. There will an offset in temperature.

With this set-up, when LED is driving heat will be more. That means the chip pad is also getting heated. When LED is at Low, the chip pad is at ambient temperature. Now the chip is also getting heated and cooled.

Consider an ambient temperature of 40°C. LED max temp will go up to 120°C. When LED reaches 120°C, LED gets turned off then turned back on at 100°C. When LED goes off, the temperature will decrease quickly and when it turns on, the temp will start to increase.

My question is: is it a good thing with respect to the microcontroller, rated -45..125°C?

Comment: Which MCU? How much power it dissipates? What is the thermal resistance for it? Is the 125 °C rating for the silicon die?

Comment: A bang-bang (full on/full off) control algorithm doesn't make sense here. Use PWM to regulate the temperature linearly. Less thermal stress for both the controller and the LED.

Answer (score 2):

All characteristics of a MCU is specified for a certain temperature range. If you stay within those limits and buy a part from a well-known vendor, you should be able to trust the characteristics.

The normal operating temp. range ("industrial") is -40 to 85°C. This includes temperature variations inside that range. If you need to go beyond that, you need a part with extended temp range or even automotive or military spec. Which in turn means it's already a bad thing in terms of price and availability.

And then you need to read carefully what exactly this temperature means: is it specified for junction or ambient? And there may be various thermal resistance and dissipation parameters - this is a big topic of it's own (and I'm far from an expert of it).

Is it bad for the MCU? Well... yes. Things like flash data retention and write cycles etc are specified within the temperature range. But if you keep well below the maximum, the memory will last much longer. So instead of lets say 15 years of data retention, you might get 100 years if you always keep the part below 50° or whatever.

And then another issue is oxidation, depending on ventilation and how/where the product is used. Rapid heating cooling of normal air will mean extra stress in the form of moist air getting cooled down. This isn't good for solder joints or metal surfaces in general. All the moisture will end up on the coolest metal surface of the product, wherever that happens to be. You might need some PCB coating for this, of a kind which can handle the temperatures. Which in turn might be expensive.

And then obviously all other parts on the PCB have similar temperature considerations. Crystals/oscillators, resistors, capacitors... which in turn will affect the MCU.

Comment: Thank you , now i got an idea